# how to format a USB drive in ZFS under Ubuntu precise (12.04) (32bit)

Tags: zfs

I am running Ubuntu precise 32 bits:

```
$uname -a
Linux thorin 3.2.0-30-generic-pae #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 17:14:09 UTC 2012 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

1. What is the command line to format an external USB HDD in ZFS ? (I am not interested in multi-disk pools for the moment).
2. Is it advisable to use ZFS with a 32-bit kernel? (the instructions on [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#HowDoIInstallIt) call for a 64-bit kernel but Ubuntu precise has a recommended 32-bit kernel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first off you need to ensure that you have `zfs` installed on your system.

On Ubuntu you can run:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-zfs
```

Then you can follow through with the "Getting Started" in the official ZFS documentation: http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/intro

The reason "ZFS on Linux" recommends 64 bit is because of kernel compatibility. See: http://zfsonlinux.org/faq.html#WhatKernelVersionsAreSupported

There is also an article [here](https://github.com/dajhorn/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-to-a-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem) that shows formatting the disks, etc.